# bash (and others) do not receive ^O

Tags: terminal, keyboard, command-line, bash

Under `Terminal.app` and `iTerm2`, the key combination `^O` is not received by many terminal programs.

For example, `/bin/bash` does not receive `^O`. Indeed, if `/bin/bash` could receive `^O`, then `^V^O` would output `^O` (see `quoted-insert` in `bash(1)`). However, `^V^O` produces no output, and bash remains in quoted-insert mode: it outputs the next character it receives verbatim. Similarly, `neomutt` does not receive `^O` when compiled with ncurses (but it receives `^O` when compiled with s-lang).

In contrast, `/bin/zsh` and `vim` correctly outputs `^O` after `^V^O`.

What is going on? I thought it could be due to an ncurses bug, but I can reproduce the behaviour in both programs compiled using the built-in ncurses library, and an updated copy of ncurses:

```
bash-3.2$ otool -L /bin/bash /bin/zsh /opt/local/bin/neomutt /opt/local/bin/vim | egrep '(:|curse)'
/bin/bash:
        /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.0)
/bin/zsh:
        /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.0)
/opt/local/bin/neomutt:
        /opt/local/lib/libncurses.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.0.0)
/opt/local/bin/vim:
        /opt/local/lib/libncurses.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.0.0)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/ctrl-o-behavior-in-terminal-app/3255#3255) answer your question?

Comment: Yes, could you please mark this as a duplicate? Alternatively, I can delete the question.

Comment: I've requested that it be marked as a duplicate.